# Adding CUDA to WFA

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to use cuda kernels(some of CUPTI samples included in Cuda Toolkit to get info about GPU and performance) in WFA application.
How I should do it?

When I try to add .cu file it shows me this type of errors:

"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

The things that are underlined are cuda include files and therefore other cuda elements.

Just to be clear I can run CUDA runtime projects, and cuda applications - it causes no problem.

I'm using win 7, visual studio 2010, I have newest Toolkit, drivers, and Nsight.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the CUDA toolkit? Have you installed the CUDA SDK correctly? Are you able to compile the examples that ship with the SDK?

Comment: All the examples work fine,and sdk is installed properly. Maybe I've missed sth in Documentation and that is why I want sb to answer my Q.

Comment: There probably is something to do with project options, but I'm new to Visual studio and i don't know what to do. I'm trying to add .cu file to the WFA project. Or should i do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

In solution explorer you click right on you project and choose "Build Customizations..." and then you check "CUDA 4.X(.targets,.props)".